# Insert into JList with an animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlist

I'd like to insert JComponents into the top of a JList.  Specifically, I want to have it look like the item is being pushed down.  I think I have the needed logic for the animation but I don't know how to make the JList animate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've ended up doing is this, the ListCellRenderer uses a hash map to keep track of the progress of the animation for each song.  The animation basically just increases the height of the JComponent the ListCellRenderer returns from 0 to 100, and when a new item is inserted a Timer starts that keeps calling the repaint method until the animation completes.  I had this all from the start but the key thing is that the animation doesn't seem to work unless I replace the ListCellRenderer with a brand new one at each iteration.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    cards.setCellRenderer(new ItemRenderer(cardsPane));
    repaint();
    if(animation.done){
        timer.stop()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to first render your component to an [`BufferedImage`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and then render the animation in the [GlassPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) (above the actual component).

This looks like a related article: [How to use glass pane for animation (SwingX and Timingframework)](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=16)

Comment: I don't think that's quite what I want.  I'm looking to have the new component visible shove the others as it moves in.